# vTiger crm change modules config

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

I want to add new module and deactivate some controlls(left panel and bottom header). Where is some file(config) in which I can write some conditions for this?
I want to safe for this module only top header.
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are common Operations which will be included for all modules. So make sure if you wants to remove then set proper conditions to hide it. If you wants to remove then you can find those tpl files related to it.

1) Sidebar File
- \layouts\vlayout\modules\Vtiger\SideBar.tpl

2) Header File
- \layouts\vlayout\modules\Vtiger\CommonActions.tpl